# Installed cairosvg and cairocffi but gives error on import

Tags: python, python-3.x, cairo

When I try to install `cairosvg` it says requirement satisfied.

```
Requirement already satisfied: cairosvg in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: cairocffi in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from cairosvg)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from cairosvg)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from cairosvg)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from cairosvg)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from cairosvg)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=0.6 in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from cairocffi->cairosvg)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from pillow->cairosvg)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in 
c:\users\kshitij\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from cffi>=0.6->cairocffi->cairosvg)
```

But when I try to import it in IDLE, it gives the following error:

```
import cairosvg
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
 from . import surface
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 24, in <module>
import cairocffi as cairo
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
cairo = dlopen(ffi, *CAIRO_NAMES)
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 34, in dlopen
return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cffi\api.py", line 140, in dlopen
lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cffi\api.py", line 786, in _make_ffi_library
backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cffi\api.py", line 781, in _load_backend_lib
raise OSError(msg)
OSError: cannot load library libcairo.so.2: error 0x7e.  Additionally, 
ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 
'libcairo.so.2'
```

This might be because of`cairocffi` as it is also giving the following error on import:

```
import cairocffi
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
cairo = dlopen(ffi, 'cairo', 'cairo-2')
File "C:\Users\Kshitij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 38, in dlopen
raise OSError("dlopen() failed to load a library: %s" % ' / '.join(names))
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
```

I have a 64-bit windows based architecture with python 3.5 and have installed cairocffi-0.8.0 which installed without a problem.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using [UniConverter2.0](https://sk1project.net/uc2/).
My environments is

- Python 3.7
- Windows 10 x64

1. Install [uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi](https://downloads.sk1project.net/uniconvertor/2.0rc4/uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi),
2. Find the "dll" sub-directory under the UniConverter installation path.(In my case, `C:\Program Files\UniConvertor-2.0rc4\dlls`)
3. Add this "dll" path to the system path.
4. Close VSCode(or other editor) and reopen the project.
5. Try to run your code again.
   Enjoy!